# jQuery if input value matches character in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my html

```
<input type="text" />
<div>
  <p>Apple</p>
  <p>Peach</p>
  <p>Bannana</p>
  <p>Tomato</p>
</div>
```

And my jQuery code yet

```
var items = $("div").find("p").text();

console.log(items);
```

How can I highlight each character inside div p that matches value in input? Let's say that users write down in input character "a". Page should look like this, even A character in apple should be bold.

**A**pple

Pe**a**ch

B**a**nn**a**n**a**

Tom**a**to

here is [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PzVdyw?editors=1011) as well

Comment: Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. That would really helps us to figure out the issue with your code. Thanks!

Comment: Man, there are tons of answers here on SO. You may have a look at [mark.js](https://markjs.io)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is:

```
// Borrowed from:
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript#answer-3561711
function escapeRegex(str) {
   return str.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
}

var items = $("div").find("p");

$('input').on('keyup', function() {
   var reg = new RegExp('(' + escapeRegex(this.value) + ')', 'gi');
   items.html(function() {
      return this.textContent.replace(reg, "<b>$1</b>");
   });
});
```

Note that above answer assumes (based on the posted markup) that `p` elements only have text contents. If the `p` elements have child elements then another option should be considered as the code snippet can have side effects and create *invalid* markup.

https://jsfiddle.net/xbqetxdo/

Comment: Using innerHTML is evil, will destroy events and triggers regeneration of the DOM

Comment: @dude Yes, in some cases, modifying `innerHTML` property of the `body` element, as an example, is, of course, a terrible idea. But the above answer somehow only modifies the _textContent_ of an element, it assumes (based on the posted markup) that `p` elements only have text contents and you can't bind event handlers to text nodes after all, right? So you won't lose any event handlers in this case, also this question is not related to event bindings and for dynamic elements one can use event delegation.